# nodeJS request method not working, I am Pay as you go Plan

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, api-ai

I am trying to hit a Railway API from firebase cloud function and it giving me the below error

I heard that request method doesn't work free plan, but its still not working even after I upgraded to pay as you go plan

// See https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs
// for Dialogflow fulfillment library docs, samples, and to report issues

```
'use strict';
var request = require('request');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));


  function fallback(agent) {
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
}

   function welcome(agent) {

      var options = {
            url: 'http://api.railwayapi.com/v2/live/train/' + '17239' + '/date/' + '27-12-2018' + '/apikey/' + 'myjwjpywq4'
        }
        request(options, function (err, resp, body) {
console.log(body);

        })



     agent.add(`This message is from Dialogflow's Cloud Functions for Firebase editor!`);
         agent.add(new Suggestion(`Quick Reply`));
     agent.add(new Suggestion(`Suggestion`));
     agent.setContext({ name: 'weather', lifespan: 2, parameters: { city: 'Rome' }});
   }

  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
 agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Error:

```
TypeError: request is not a function
    at welcome (/user_code/index.js:33:9)
    at WebhookClient.handleRequest (/user_code/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:303:44)
    at exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment.functions.https.onRequest (/user_code/index.js:71:9)
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:57:9)
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:725:7
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:708:11
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
```

Comment: You are trying to call something that isn't a function in index.js at line 33?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the entire, minimal code that reproduces the problem.  Without that, we can only guess what you might have done wrong.

Comment: please check now @DougStevenson

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two definitions for `request`.  Here's the first one:

```
var request = require('request');
```

Here's the second one, and it's masking the first one inside the body of your function:

```
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
```

When you call request() inside the body of your function, JavaScript thinks you mean the innermost `request`, which is the first argument passed to it.  This is obviously not what you intended.  At that point, `request` is not a function.

Just give them different names so they don't collide with each other.